# Group posts by Year - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railscasts

I have model called "Shoes" that belongs to the a model called "History". I want to show all of the shoes in my History show.html.erb page, but I want to group them by their release date. (I have an attribute called release for that).

I'm using this example from Railscasts:

**shoes_controller**

```
def index
  @shoes = Shoe.all(:order => 'release, name')
  @release_year = @shoes.group_by { |t| t.release.beginning_of_year }
end
```

**Shoes index.html.erb view**

```
<% @release_year.each do |release, shoes| %>
  <% shoes.each do |shoe| %> 
     <%= shoe.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want to be able to do this but on my **History** show.html page, how can i accomplish this?

What I have so far:

**History show.html.erb**

```
<% @history.shoes.each do |shoe| %> 
  <div class="shoe">
     <%= shoe.name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you may want to create a _shoes_by_year partial in the shoe views, and then render the shoe collection:

views/shoes/_shoe.html.erb

```
<div class=shoe>
    <%= shoe.name %>
</div>
```

views/shoes/_shoes_by_year.html.erb

```
<% shoes_by_year.each do |release_year, shoes| %>
   <div>
     <h3><%= release_year.year %></h3>
     <%= render 'shoes/shoe', collection: shoes %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

histories_controller.rb

```
def show
  ...
  @shoes = @history.shoes.group_by { |shoe| shoe.release.at_beginning_of_year } 
end
```

/views/history/show.html.erb

```
...
<%= render 'shoes/shoes_by_year', object => @shoes %>
```