# Rails 4: Displaying a table of a collection of items, sorted by various item attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a `CareerEntry` model that has the following attributes: `name, job_category, company, group, location, year, full_intern`, and it represents the job offers that people have received. `full_intern` is a string that is either "internship" or "full-time", and represents what the type of the job offer is. All CareerEntries will be created by an Admin interface, so it is essentially acting as a standalone model. This is my question: given a bunch of CareerEntry objects, I want to display a table to display on my careers page (which has an action in a `PagesController`).

I want the table to be sorted according to multiple attributes. I want each year to be its own section in the table, then within each year, I want the internship entries grouped together and the full-time entries grouped together. Then, within these groupings, I want each job_category to be its own section (job_categories comprise of things like 'Investment Banking,' or 'Technology.')

A very good example of what I'm going for is shown under the "2013" tab in [this link.](http://www.dsp-rho.com/careers/)

What is the best way to go about achieving this? I know that in the `careers` action definition of my `PagesController`, I could have:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

    def careers
        @careerentries = CareerEntry.order(:year => :desc, :fullintern => :asc, :job_category => :asc)
    end

end
```

But this would simply return all the entries in the order that I want, and would not allow me to place headers and dividers to separate, say, the job_categories.

Is there any easier way of achieving what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for [.group_by](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by)?

---

**Group By**

From the link you gave, it looks like you want to group your results by year, like this:

```
@careerentries = CareerEntry.order(year: :desc, fullintern: :asc, job_category: :asc)
@entries_by_year = @careerentries.group_by { |entry| entry.year }
```

This gives you all the data, ordered to your specs. You can then sort through it, using the `group_by` method:

```
@entries_by_year.each do |entry|
    entry.name
end
```

You could then work this into your table

Good reference [Group posts by Year - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537586/group-posts-by-year-rails)